# FactoryGirl: specifying attributes on associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have two simple factories: One for `user` and one for `blog`.  When creating a blog, it must have an associated `user`, so this is reflected in the blog factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :blog do
    user #specifying the required association
  end
end
```

Now I can create a blog in a spec like so:

```
blog = create(:blog)
```

what I am not sure of how to do in the spec is how to specify some *custom attributes on the associated `user` record* immediately when the `blog` record is first created.

For example: when creating the `blog` record (which also creates an associated `user` record), I want to specify the `first_name` attribute on that associated `user` record.  Something like:

```
blog = create(:blog, associated_user: (first_name: 'foobar) )
```

That syntax up above doesn't work but I want to do something like that.  I did look at the [factory girl docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md), and I have been googling but have been unable to figure this one out.

**Question**:  How do I set some custom attributes on an associated object when creating an object with factory girl?

Comment: Have you looked at associations in the FactoryGirl docs? I think what you are looking for is called a transient http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations

Comment: @JeffPrice yes I did look at the associations section.  It does not show how I can custom type in the attributes within the actual spec.  All I saw was that it shows how to use inheritance for a factory so that you can specify associated traits that way, but that feels like overkill because I only want to specify these attributes for one small spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set the corresponding call argument with the needed Object.

```rb
user = create(:user, first_name: "Harald")
blog = create(:blog, user: user)
# or inline if preferred
blog = create(:blog, user: create(:user, first_name: "Heinz"))
```

Note: Don't forget to rather use build than create wherever possible to speedup your tests :)